# Filtered Windows comand works on it's own inside WSL, but not in a script

Tags: bash

I have this command which returns an IP successfully:

```
user@laptop:~$ systeminfo.exe | sed -n '/Connection Name: vEthernet (WSL)/,+4p' | egrep --word-regexp '\[01\]:' | awk '{print $2}'
172.22.0.1
```

I am trying to concatenate and export an environmental variable `DISPLAY` using a script with this content:

```
LOCAL_IP=$(systeminfo.exe | sed -n '/Connection Name: vEthernet (WSL)/,+4p' | egrep --word-regexp '\[01\]:' | awk '{print $2}')
export DISPLAY=$LOCAL_IP:0
```

But after this script runs, `DISPLAY` doesn't look like expected:

```
user@laptop:~$ echo $DISPLAY
:02.22.0.1
```

I was expecting an answer `172.22.0.1:0`. What went wrong?

Comment: `export DISPLAY="${LOCAL_IP}:0"`

Comment: @0stone0 This did not solve the problem.

Comment: How are you running the script? Child processes can't change their parent's environment, so exporting a variable in a script won't export the new value back to your shell. You'd have to source the script to edit your current environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LOCAL_IP` appears to have a trailing `\r`; `od -c <<< "${LOCAL_IP}"` should show the value ending in a `\r`

One fix using parameter substitution:

```
$ export DISPLAY="${LOCAL_IP//$'\r'/}:0"
$ echo "${DISPLAY}"
172.22.0.1:0
```

Another option would be to add an additional pipe on the end of OP's current command, a couple ideas (`dos2unix`, `tr -d '\r'`); 3rd option modifies the `awk` script to remove the `\r`:

```
systeminfo.exe | sed -n '/Connection Name: vEthernet (WSL)/,+4p' | egrep --word-regexp '\[01\]:' | awk '{print $2}' | dos2unix

# or

systeminfo.exe | sed -n '/Connection Name: vEthernet (WSL)/,+4p' | egrep --word-regexp '\[01\]:' | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '\r'

# or

systeminfo.exe | sed -n '/Connection Name: vEthernet (WSL)/,+4p' | egrep --word-regexp '\[01\]:' | awk '{gsub(/\r/,"");print $2}'
```

Another option would be to replace the `sed/egrep/awk/tr` with a single `awk` call.  If OP wants to go  this route I'd recommend asking a new question, making sure to provide the complete output from `systeminfo.exe` to better understand the parsing requirements.